# Inserir vídeo embed com mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site para simplificar a busca de vídeos educacionais para meu TCC.

Fiz um sistema com dois combo box para pesquisar as disciplinas no banco de dados e os conteúdos, sendo conteúdos uma foreign key de disciplinas.

```
<h2 class="title">Selecione a disciplina</h2>
        <form action="" method="get">
        <div class="box">
          <select name="disciplina" id="disciplina">
            <option value="" selected = selected>Selecione uma disciplina</option>
              <?php
              if($num_logar > 0) {
                  do {
                  echo "<option value='".$fet_logar['disciplina_id']."'>".$fet_logar['disciplina_nome']."</option>";
                  }while($fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar));
              }
              ?>
        </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <h2 class="title">Selecione o conteúdo</h2>
        <div class="box">
        <select name="conteudo" id="conteudo">    
        </select>
        </form>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#disciplina').change(function(){
                $('#conteudo').load('conteudo.php?disciplina='+$('#disciplina').val());

            });
        });
        </script>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, após o usuário selecionar uma disciplina, aparecerá seus respectivos conteúdos em outra combo box, sendo feita com javascript.

Porém a partir que o usuário selecionou o conteúdo quero que apareça de forma automática, buscado do mysql, o link do vídeo embed do youtube.

Fiz isso de forma não automática para uma representação. Segue o código abaixo.

```
<figure>
  <div class="boxVideo">
  <iframe  width="700" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  </figure>
```

Como eu faço para que de forma automática, o link de vídeo embed, após selecionar o conteúdo de determinada disciplina, apareça abaixo da página?

Ilustração do BD:
Tabela disciplina, assim como o combo box que demonstra as disciplinas

[image: Tabela disciplina, assim como o combo box que demonstra as cadastradas]

Tabela conteúdo, com uma FK, para que ao selecionar a disciplina o conteúdo a ser mostrado prevalecerá a partir de qual disciplina foi selecionada

[image: Tabela conteúdo, com uma FK, para que ao selecionar a disciplina o conteúdo a ser mostrado prevalecerá a partir de qual disciplina foi selecionada]

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** A partir de uma resposta anterior, foi observado que:

**1-** O select de conteúdo é puxado a partir de um javascript, ou seja, o value dele equivale ao conteudo_id e seguindo ao value name.

**2-** Uma ideia de solução seria um campo como eu fiz na tabela "*conteudo*", *conteudo_video*, que neste campo entraria o código embed do vídeo, exemplo "wjwudahw12" que entraria em "youtube.com/embed/wjwudahw12", como posso editar o "frame", para que ele percorresse por este campo, após selecionar disciplina e conteúdo, e inserir o código embed respectivo.

Comment: Terá que pegar o evento do combo box

Comment: E é isso que não sei fazer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, parece que o problema está em solucionar problemas de *client-side* com programação *server-side*.

Você está tentando carregar um conteúdo dentro do **select**, para fazer isso utilize a função `$.get` do `jQuery`:

```
var conteudos = $.get('conteudo.php?disciplina='+$('#disciplina').val());
```

Esta pagina `conteudo.php` deve retornar um **JSON**:

```
[
  {
    value: "F9Bo89m2f6g",
    name: "Video 1"
  },
  {
    value: "AF7M17QX4QE",
    name: "Video 2"
  }
]
```

Para assim, você conseguir popular o **select** desta forma:

```
    $.each(conteudos, function (key, conteudo) {
      $("#conteudo")
        .append(
          "<option value=" + conteudo.value + ">" + conteudo.name + "</option>"
        );
    });
```

Para mostrar o video você pode utilizar o value do **select** dos conteúdos, assim:

```
$("#conteudo").change(function () {
    var codigoVideo = $("#conteudo").val();
    var videoContainer = $("#video_container");
    videoContainer.html(`
    <iframe width="700" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${codigoVideo}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`);
  });
```

Aqui está um exemplo funcionando:
https://codepen.io/kleberoliveira/pen/gOpNwYP

Comment: Opa @Kleber Oliveira, obrigado pela ajuda! Consegui entender, e é bem isso mesmo que preciso! Porém como posso sincronizar para que os vídeos cadastrados sejam puxados do mysql?

Comment: @Matheus você precisa que o arquivo [conteúdo.php]  puxe do banco mysql esta informação. acredito que usando o a lib PDO e um simples query SELECT, e utilizando o `json_encode` do PHP solucione este problema. Não se esqueça de avaliar a ajuda e fechar a pergunta no stackoverflow.

Comment: Você utilizou o js para aparecer o vídeo ali, certo? como:   {
    value: "F9Bo89m2f6g",
    name: "Video 1"
  },

Comment: Como fica dai para puxar este value do banco de dados? Não entendo muito bem de js

Comment: você tem um campo `conteudo_video` utilize ele para guardar o código do video do youtube. ex: "F9Bo89m2f6g"

Comment: Claro. Irei registrar todos os códigos ali. Mas para inserir eles no js? Como fica?

Comment: `var conteudos = $.get('conteudo.php?disciplina='+$('#disciplina').val());` crie um arquivo `conteudo.php` que o resultado seja como o **JSON** indicado.

Comment: teria como fazer para mim? não sou mt experiente em js, to boiando demais kk

Comment: não é um problema de **JS**, mas fiz o código **PHP** segue o link: https://repl.it/@KleberOliveira/SimplePDOSelect

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106363/discussion-between-matheus-and-kleber-oliveira).

Comment: lhe encaminhei o código php no chat.